# Has there been any modern usage of the haftaros for Matos - Vayeilech? (COVID or other reasons)

Tags: haftarah

Under normal circumstances, Matos (sometimes Pinchas) through Vayeilech (sometimes Haazinu) are read during the weeks before and after Tisha Be'av and Shabbos Shuva.  Their haftaros therefore get replaced with the haftaros for that time of year.

In principle, those parshiyos could be read at a different time.  For example, in 2020 a shul might have been closed during the summer (probably not in the US, but maybe in other places?) and decided to read 2 or 3 parshiyos each week until they caught up to the normal schedule.  If that happened, and one of those parshiyos was read last at another time of year, I imagine they would have read the "proper" haftarah for the parsha.  Did that happen anywhere?

I also heard that R' Hershel Schachter allowed a shul to let a boy who missed his bar mitzvah read "his" parsha from a second Sefer Torah, and since that extra reading closed off the leining, he would read the haftarah connected to that parsha.  Has that ever happened, because of COVID or otherwise, and resulted in one of those usually overridden haftaros being read?

Or any other scenario I'm not thinking of?

Comment: Note the italian rite to this day only does about half of the special ones (devrim through reeh). Does that count or do you want within those who usually do all ~11?

Comment: @DoubleAA for this question I'm more interested in a haftarah being read by a community that doesn't normally read it

Comment: It's pretty unlikely since presumably anyone catching up would probably try to be done by simchas torah, and in 2020 there wasn't even a shabbos between shuva and sukkos for this to be relevant. Never say never I guess.

Comment: I strongly suspect that any shul "machmir" enough to play catch-up like that would be terrified of digging up a haftarah not found in the standard chumashim ... "could lead to mixed dancing!" or something like that. Of course our heterodox co-religionists on the triennial cycle did contemplate a bunch of new haftarahs, but instead just read whatever's set for the annual cycle -- though that means they may read, for instance, the haftarah about Shimshon the Nazir after reading a third of Nasso that doesn't discuss Nazir.

Comment: @Shalom More than just contemplated. There is a psak allowing it to be done. I don’t know if any do it in practice though https://www.rabbinicalassembly.org/sites/default/files/public/halakhah/teshuvot/2011-2020/triennial-haftarot.pdf

Comment: @Shalom On the contrary, people catching up are actually ok with knowing about old haftarot. If we're stereotyping, the strongest arguments for catching up are from the diversity of historical leining customs, something someone afraid of digging out old haftaras probably would rather also pretend doesn't exist. It's only the people who follow a random acharon's svara without being aware of the history that would have allowed you not to catch up.

Comment: @DoubleAA actually on a related note, if they hadn't managed to catch up by Simchas Torah they'd probably read just the first half of Vezos Habracha and then haftarah from Melachim!